# How to disable form going to fullscreen mode when double clicked

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-desktop

When double clicking on C# Desktop .Net form, then the form goes fullscreen.
How can i disable this function?

(It only goes fullscreen when double clicking on the Base of the form)

I am using FormBorderstyle - None.

Comment: Sounds more like a windows 10 desktop manager function that one(in my test on this browser window, double clicking then the vertical drag arrows were showing, mouse at the bottom border, the window expanded vertically to take up as much vertical space as possible), or your form has a double click handler that is doing it

Comment: Is this the only kind of resizing event you're trying to prevent? If you want to prevent *any* resizing, you could create a handler for [Control.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resize?view=netframework-4.8) and just set the size to some predetermined value.

Comment: @itsme86 It is the only resizing i am trying to prevent.